# Moving MediatR from a MVC project to Razor Pages. Cannot get basic syntax to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, mediatr

The working MVC version is

```
 public class StatCategoriesController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<StatCategoryPreviewDto>>> GetStatCategoryPreview([FromQuery] GetStatCategoryPreviewQuery query)
    {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(query));
    }    
}
```

The RAZOR version is

```
  public class CategoriesModel : PageModel
{
    private IMediator _mediator;

    protected IMediator Mediator =>
        _mediator ?? (_mediator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>());

    public async Task<IEnumerable<StatCategoryPreviewDto>> OnGet([FromQuery] GetStatCategoryPreviewQuery query)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(query);
    }

}
```

And the RAZOR verion doesn't return the JSON.. instead it returns..

nvalidOperationException: Unsupported handler method return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Srx.Application.StatCategories.Models.StatCategoryPreviewDto]]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.CreateHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerDescriptor)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A razor page method should return type that implements `IActionResult` in order to properly execute action result. If you need to return json you can use `JsonResult` and changing action return type to `IActionResult` will be enough

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet([FromQuery] GetStatCategoryPreviewQuery query)
{
    var result = await Mediator.Send(query);
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```